# Type inference of functions as arguments

Tags: f#

I would like to write a function which takes several tupples as arguments and choose theirs ith elements and passes to another function, where i is given as another argument. I've tried sth like this:

```
let function (tup1:'A*'A) (tup2:'B*'B) i =
    otherFunction (i tup1) (i tup2)
function Tup1 Tup2 fst
```

I've got an error, because `i` was expected to be `'A*'A ->'A` not `'B*'B->'B`. 
Is it any way to make this code to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think about it: what is the _type_ of `i`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically want to pass an argument of type `∀'a.'a*'a->'a`, but in F# (and other MLs), only [rank-1 polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism#Higher-ranked_polymorphism) is supported so you can't do this directly.  The workaround is to define a new type with a generic method to emulate higher-rank polymorphism:

```
type Untupler =
    abstract Apply : 'a*'a -> 'a

let myFunction tup1 tup2 (i:Untupler) =
    otherFunction (i.Apply tup1) (i.Apply tup2)

myFunction Tup1 Tup2 { new Untupler with member __.Apply (x,y) = x }
```

Comment: Excellent. Such an illuminating and short answer.

Comment: Rather : { new Untupler with member __.Apply (x,y) = fst (x,y) } // See this follow-up question : 32177835. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177835/type-inference-on-abstract-type-with-a-tuple)

Comment: Thanks for the correction (and sorry for the mistake - I wasn't in front of a compiler when I wrote my answer).  Another fix would be to leave the implementation unchanged but to declare `Apply` like this: `abstract Apply : ('a*'a) -> 'a`.

Answer (score 3):

When you use the function `i` with `tup1`, it's inferred to be of the type `'A * 'A -> 'A`. This means that when you use it with `tup2`, the only way that can work is if `tup2` is *also* an `'A * 'A`.

The function `i` can't change type within the same function. If there's a way to do what you want, I'm not aware of it, but you can sidestep the issue like this:

```
let myFunction x y =
    otherFunction x y
```

Call it like this:

```
myFunction (fst tup1) (fst tup2)
```

This puts slightly more responsibility of the caller, but the advantage is that it's possible :)