# type inference on abstract type with a tuple

Tags: f#

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156122/type-inference-of-functions-as-arguments) kvb's answer, this code compiles (F#4) and runs :

```
type Untupler = abstract Apply : 'u * 'u -> 'u

let myotherFun arg1 arg2 =
    printfn "myotherFun result is : %A %A" arg1 arg2

let myFunction tup1 tup2 (i:Untupler) =
    myotherFun (i.Apply tup1) (i.Apply tup2)

let reskvb = myFunction (1,2) ("Hello","World") { new Untupler with member __.Apply (x,y) = snd (x,y) }
```

But if the last line is replaced by the initial answer :

```
let reskvb = myFunction (1,2) ("Hello","World") { new Untupler with member __.Apply x = fst x }
```

then the compiler complains with error FS0768 :
**The member 'Apply' does not accept the correct number of arguments, 2 arguments are expected**

I do not understand why the compiler seems to fail to infer that x is indeed a tuple. Or is there another issue I am missing ? Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is that when you start using interfaces, you move into F#'s support for Object-Oriented Programming, and in F#, all **OOP interop methods are tupled by default**.

Thus, the `Apply` method is interpreted as being a method that takes two method arguments, rather than a function that takes a single tuple as input.

Comment: Thank you. We then have the choice to reitarate the type as John's answer or make the tuple explicit aka (x,y).

Comment: Those are the options that I can think of, but as kvp proved on that other question, that doesn't prove much. Anyway, if you only need to Adapters over `fst` and `snd`, you can once and for all define two values that does that.

Comment: There can be more than two values, starting with variations including side effects such as : let fst' t = printfn "Hi! \n" ; fst t. So @kvb's approach makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Yes, I'm only saying that instead of passing an inline object expression every time you have to pass an `Untupler` value, you might want to define two well-known values, like e.g. `Untupler.fst` and `Untupler.snd`.

Comment: One alternative is to alter the method's declaration so that it takes an explicit tuple and then leave the implementation alone.  I added a comment to this effect under my answer to the other question.